# VB.NET - Create Nullable(Of T) with HasValue = False

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, datetime, nullable

I'm working against a SQL Server database that regularly has DateTime columns that can be null. I'm using LINQ to SQL to connect my WinForms (VB.NET) program to the data.

I've extended some of the LINQ objects and added a couple of `Nullable(Of DateTime)` properties. Basically, I'm calculating whether a particular value exists. The value is a `DateTime`. If it doesn't exist, I want to create a `Nullable(Of DateTime)` object (structure, whatever) with the `HasValue` property set to `False`.

I did some research, and apparently, the New constructor on a `Nullable(Of T)` creates one with `HasValue` set to True.

Two questions:

1. Why is this? Since the `Nullable(Of T)` structure was created specifically for this type of situation, why would the default behavior be `HasValue` = `True`?
2. What's the best way to initialize a `Nullable(Of T)` to actually be `null`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're supplying a value to the `Nullable` constructor then it will have the given value, which would result in the scenario you're describing where `HasValue` is true.

To declare a nullable with a `HasValue` of `false` you can take either of these approaches:

```
Dim x As Nullable(Of DateTime)
Dim y As DateTime?
```

However, if you're using the constructor and supplying a value, the nullable struct won't have a null value, and it's `HasValue` would be `true`:

```
Dim z As New Nullable(Of DateTime)(DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ahmad's answer is good. There is also an empty constructor, even though strangely, there's no trace of it on MSDN:

```
Dim x As New Nullable(Of DateTime)
Debug.Assert(x.HasValue = False)
```

As expected, HasValue is false. If you have a Nullable(T) with a value, and want to remove that value, you'd just set it to Nothing, as if it was a reference type:

```
x = New Date(2011, 1, 1)
x = Nothing
Debug.Assert(x.HasValue = False)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I'm almost positive that I was trying to use `Dim x as New Nullable(Of DateTime)` and was getting back an object with `HasValue = True` and `Value = '1/1/0001 00:00'`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: There's a reason I put those Debug.Assert in the sample code, I ran this code and the Asserts guarantee that HasValue is indeed false ;-)